# Scrape data from espn statsguru

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract specific rows from this link using beautifulsoup:

> http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/37000.html?class=2;template=results;type=batting

I just want the rows begining with the words `year 20XX` (where XX means any year).

The data looks like this:

```
year 1994       18  17  1   348 90  21.75   491 70.87   0   2   1   25  2
year 1995       16  16  2   514 78* 36.71   637 80.69   0   4   1   44  3
year 1996       21  21  2   708 106* 7.26   957 73.98   1   5   0   71  1
.
.
2007
```

Ayone?

Comment: Can you share any code with us? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. The website you are scraping from has multiple bodies with multiple rows that have the same class which can sometimes make it difficult to separate the ones you want. For example, each row on that page has a tag of `<tr>`, which specifies a row in `HTML`. These `<tr>` tags each have the same class of "data1", like so: `<tr class="data1">...</tr>`. All you have to do is check if the current row contains the word "year." To do this, you can perform a simple `if` statement to check if the word "year" is in the row:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

link = "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/37000.html?class=2;template=results;type=batting"

result = requests.get(link)
source = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

for i in soup.findAll("tr", {"class":"data1"}):
    text = i.text
    # checking if the row contains the word "year"
    if "year" in text:
        # do stuff with text
        print(text)
```

**EDIT**
[Responding to comment]

Replace the previous `if` statement with this:

```
if "year" in text:
        row = text.strip().split("\n")
        if '' in row: row.remove('')
        runs = row[4]
        print(runs)
```

First, I iterate over each element of the row. The `.strip()` and `.split()` methods I use will get rid of the whitespaces and `\n` from the row. This stores each value nicely in a list, like so:

```
['year 1994', '', '18', '17', '1', '348', '90', '21.75', '491', '70.87', '0', '2', '1', '25', '2']
```

However, as you can see there is a blank space (' ') at index postion 1 in the list. To remove this from the list, I use a simple `if` statement to remove the blank space if it is present:

```
if '' in row: row.remove('')
```

This leaves you with a nicely cleaned list with all of the elements of each year:

```
['year 1994', '18', '17', '1', '348', '90', '21.75', '491', '70.87', '0', '2', '1', '25', '2']
```

Each value in the list is now an element from the row on the website. Checking back to the website, we can see that the runs for `year 1994` is `348`. This is at the fourth index of the row. We can use this information to get only the runs from each year by usng:

```
runs = row[4]
```

**Final output:**

```
348
514
708
423
806
332
577
457
772
681
921
439
390
669
```

Comment: Thanks. Also i want to ask you one thing..is their a way in which ..suppose in the row ``` year 1994       18  17  1   348 90  21.75   491 70.87   0   2   1   25  2``` , i want to get only the runs , i.e, 348 as output. Can i get it?
You can see , the whole row is basically - ```Mat   Inns  NO  Runs  HS  Ave  BF SR 100 50 0  4s 6s```